# Spring Looking at Default Value Before Resolving Placeholder

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, spring-integration

I've been searching forever for an issue similar to mine, but wasn't able to find one. Thus, I hope it's not a duplicate post.

Well,
I'm using spring integration to search for documents in my mongodb. Once it finds one, it sends the payload to another method.
I have a property file that I want to be resolved on this find and send configuration, so I use placeholders instead of static values.

Here's my xml:

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter id="sendClientMailInboundAdapter"
            expression="@repository.findClient()"
            channel="sendClientMailChannel"
            auto-startup="${send.mail.active:false}">
            <int:poller fixed-rate="${send.mail.poller.time:60}" time-unit="SECONDS" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
        </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

        <int:channel id="sendClientMailChannel" />

        <int:service-activator input-channel="sendClientMailChannel" expression="@service.sendClientMail(payload)" />
```

Right.
Now.. I've got an AppConfig class which loads the property file.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file://${appconfig.root}/appconfig.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    public static Environment env;
    ...

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer appConfigConfigurer(Environment env) {
        AppConfig.env = env;
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer appConfigConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        appConfigConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        appConfigConfigurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        return appConfigConfigurer;
    }
}
```

So.. My problem is the default value.
If I do NOT specify the default value, spring resolves the placeholder. If it's specified, though, it seems spring ignores the placeholder (maybe it doesn't wait for it to resolve) and set the default value instead!

I could use context:property-placeholder location. I've done that and it worked, but since I'm already loading the file on my configuration class, I'd rather have spring read properties from there so I would not have to remember to adjust two files in case property file changes its folder, for instance.

My question: Is there a way to tell spring to wait for the placeholder to resolve before looking at the default value?

**edit**: Just so people know.. I changed xml to java config, using placeholder / default value like before and it worked perfectly.

Here is the equivalent snippet:

```
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "sendClientMailChannel", autoStartup="${send.mail.active:false}",
                            poller = @Poller(fixedRate="${send.mail.poller.time.in.millis:60000}", maxMessagesPerPoll="1"))
public Client findClient() {
    return repository.findClient();
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="sendClientMailChannel")
public void sendToClient(Client payload) {
    service.sendClientMail(payload);
}

@Bean
public DirectChannel sendClientMailChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

note: I didn't have to ref the property file.

Comment: Do you by any chance have multiple `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`?

Comment: If yes, then this bug report: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9989 might be related.

Comment: Hmmm.. I have a "middle" project (named RestCommons) that shares codes between this and another project.
I do have PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer on RestCommons too. Could that be the problem?

Comment: It might be. I'm not sure. But going through certain links and the above bug, that issue mostly comes in case of multiple beans registered. Probably try to load both the files in the same `PropertiesPlaceHolderConfigurer` just to confirm the issue.

Comment: I just read SPR-9989 and that might be my case as well. I guess I'll have to change that xml config to java config. I think that will do since I'll get the value directly from AppConfig class. Thanks A LOT for your help.